# Use Activity View in another class

Tags: java, android

This is my activity

```
public class Conversation extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_conversation);
     }
}
```

as we see it use this layout `activity_conversation`

How can i send this layout or `View` to class for programming it like this

```
myclass m  = new myclass(View);
```

Why i want to do this because i have another class whose layout is same as  `activity_conversation`. So i want to re-use it like as: `myclass m = new mycalss(inflate layout);`

How can i get view and pass to another class to inflate it.
and is it a right approach to re-use the code?

Comment: can you make it a bit more clear?

Comment: for reuse of a layout there's the class ```Fragment``` in Android, you may check it out -> https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Comment: @RobinVinzenz but i have problem with `Fragment` i cant use it in `service` or `widnowManger`

Comment: @karanvs how can i get the `view` from activity and pass it to class ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how can i send this layout or View to class for programming it like
>   this

Do it using `getDecorView()` after calling  `setContentView` :

```
View content_layout = (View)findViewById(android.R.id.content);
myclass m  = new myclass(content_layout);
```

OR

```
ViewGroup view=(ViewGroup)getWindow().getDecorView();
LinearLayout content_layout = (LinearLayout)view.getChildAt(0);
myclass m  = new myclass(content_layout);
```

Comment: nice answer :)  :)

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
myclass m  = new myclass(View);

public myclass{
   public myclass(View yourView){
      //the variable yourView is the view passed from another class
      //you can use it 
      View myView = yourView;

   }
}
```

Comment: i just ask how can i get the `view` from activity and pass it to class?